# AccessViolationException calling Fortran from C#

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke, marshalling, access-violation

I'm trying to wrap the glmnet library (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) so I can solve <s>models</s> sparse general linear models in C#. However, the original function has a somewhat 20 parameters, so I started (completely new to Fortran) with a tiny subroutine for testing how to pass data. Unfortunately I always get an AccessViolationException.

Here's the code:

The Fortran subroutine. I compile it into a dll using the gfortran compiler that comes with Rtools (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), using the -m64 option (yes, 64bit is neccessary since I handle quite big chunks of data). Yes, the use of i could lead to out-of-bounds... but this is just for testing.

```
subroutine testaaa  (f,i,fa,ia)
real fa(i)                                                      
integer ia(i)
ia(1) = 1337
ia(i) = 666
fa(1) = 8.15
fa(i) = 333
end subroutine testaaa
```

The C# PInvoke code:

```
[DllImport("ftest.dll", EntryPoint = "testaaa_", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void Test(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float f,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int i,
    IntPtr fa,
    IntPtr ia);
```

And here is how it's called:

```
var fa = new float[4];
var ia = new int[4];
IntPtr faPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fa.Length * sizeof(float));
Marshal.Copy(fa, 0, faPtr, fa.Length);

IntPtr iaPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ia.Length * sizeof(float));
Marshal.Copy(ia, 0, iaPtr, ia.Length);

GlmnetDllWrapper.Test(0.4f, 4,faPtr,iaPtr);
```

I also tried passing the arrays directly and giving them the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] attribute. Nothing worked for me.

Do you have any suggestions where to start or what to change?

Update 1:
Even passing only the float and the int already causes the exception:

```
subroutine testbbb  (f,i)
i = 815
f = 8.15
return
end subroutine testbbb
```

C# Pinvoke and call are changed accordingly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is is possible that your Fortan library receives the parameters by pointer? Also, why are you testing everything all at once. Why have you not simplified? Can you pass a single parameter of type `int`? Of type `float`? Then try an array. Don't test the most complicated thing first. How can you tell which part fails?

Comment: OK, your update and my comment crossed. Well done for simplifying. Try passing as pointers: `public static extern void Test(ref float f, ref int i)`

Comment: Once you get past the blockage on the simple types, we can show you how to do the arrays. And there's no need for `IntPtr`. We can get the pinvoke marshaller to pin the arrays and make the calling code very simple.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `ref` does the job. Passing the arrays without any attribute works. Adding the `LPArray` attribute is just as fine. Manipulating arrays is also fine. Trying a more complex szenario now. Will comment when there's more to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your Fortran library expects the scalar parameters to be passed by reference. So you need to declare your p/invoke to match.

The array parameters can be passed quite simply as arrays and the p/invoke marshaller will pin them for you.

So, your p/invoke declaration should be like this:

```
[DllImport("ftest.dll", EntryPoint = "testaaa_")]
public static extern void Test(
    ref float f,
    ref int i,
    [In, Out] float[] fa,
    [In, Out] int[] ia
);
```

You can adjust the `[In, Out]` attributes to meet your needs.

Comment: You'd better put CalingConvention back, Fortran is almost always stdcall.  More about gfortran [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html#Interoperability-with-C)

Comment: @HansPassant `StdCall` is the default which is why I removed it. Or am I misinterpreting you?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fumbled that, sorry.  The link I left should give the OP hints what calling convention and whether or not *ref* is required from the Fortran source code.  The VALUE and USE statements matter.

Comment: Yep, I think that's it! Thanks a lot for your help! The glmnet library is working... now I have to deal with its output.
However, I left out the `In` and `Out` arguments. It works with and without them. Maybe adding them back makes the code more readable - or this there more to this?

Comment: There is a litte more. Read @Hans's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366066/are-p-invoke-in-out-attributes-optional-for-marshaling-arrays

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/chfa2zb8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx (unsafe code)
and play around with your project settings Project/Properties/Build: allow unsafe code.
But be aware of the consequences. :)

Update: Do not "play around" - I meant: "Check out the "unsafe" features".
"Unsafe" doesn't mean "dangerous".

Comment: No, please do not do this. There's no need for unsafe code. And "play around with your settings" does not an answer make.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant: "Try wrapping the area with unsafe code and allow unsafe code once" to see if the issue is located there. It's a way to handle pointers especially while working with ext. non-.Net assemblies, if "ref" doesn't work.  But you're right. It's no need, because a simple "ref" works.