# unity3d import c++ dll for pass by reference method

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, dllimport

I'd like to use c++ code in Unity3d. Normally, it is ok, i can do it by importing dll. What i'm trying to learn is whether using c++ method parameters as pass by reference is possible or not?

What i'm trying to do is getting size of uchar* array returned by c++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i'm trying to learn is whether using C++ method parameters as
>   pass by reference is possible or not?

Yes, it is possible. Use `int*` on the C++ side and `ref int` on the C# side. You should be able to write to that parameter from C++ and it will update on the C# side.

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423178/native-c-float-array-to-c-sharp-float-array-using-marshal-copy-not-working-for) answer from my other post for a complete example.

> What i'm trying to do is getting size of uchar* array returned by c++
>   code.

You can with the example above. If you care about performance, do not return array from C++. Create the array in C# then pass it to C++ and modify it there. See the linked answer for information.

Comment: thank you! i'll check and try, i hope i can work it out :)