# How to properly marshal strings from Unity to C/C++?

Tags: c#, ios, c, unity-game-engine, marshalling

The following code snippet is from Unities Bonjour client example, which demonstrates how to interact with native code from C#. It's a simple C function that returns a string back to C# (Unity):

```
char* MakeStringCopy (const char* string)
{
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(res, string);
    return res;
}

const char* _GetLookupStatus ()
{
    // By default mono string marshaler creates .Net string for returned UTF-8 C string 
    // and calls free for returned value, thus returned strings should be allocated on heap
    return MakeStringCopy([[delegateObject getStatus] UTF8String]);
}
```

The C# declaration of the function looks like:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern string _GetLookupStatus ();
```

There are a few things that puzzle me here:

1. Is this the right way to return a string from iOS native code to C#?
2. How does the returned string ever get freed?
3. Is there a better way to do it?

Any insights in this matter are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**.No.

**2**.You have to do that yourself.

**3**.Yes

If you allocate memory inside a function on the C or C++ side, you must free it. I don't see any code allocating memory on the side but I assume you left that part. Also, do not return a variable declared on the stack to C#. You will end up with undefined behavior including crashes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630063/passing-byte-array-from-c-unmanaged-dll-to-c-sharp-unity/43632320#43632320) is a C++ solution for this.

For the **C** solution:

```
char* getByteArray() 
{
    //Create your array(Allocate memory)
    char * arrayTest = malloc( 2 * sizeof(char) );

    //Do something to the Array
    arrayTest[0]=3;
    arrayTest[1]=5;

    //Return it
    return arrayTest;
}


int freeMem(char* arrayPtr){
    free(arrayPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is that the C version uses `malloc` and `free` function to allocate and de-allocate memory.

*C#*:

```
[DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr getByteArray();

[DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int freeMem(IntPtr ptr);

//Test
void Start() 
{
 //Call and return the pointer
 IntPtr returnedPtr = getIntArray();

 //Create new Variable to Store the result
 byte[] returnedResult = new byte[2];

 //Copy from result pointer to the C# variable
 Marshal.Copy(returnedPtr, returnedResult, 0, 2);

 //Free native memory
 freeMem(returnedPtr);

 //The returned value is saved in the returnedResult variable
 byte val1 = returnedResult[0];
 byte val2 = returnedResult[1];
}
```

Note that this is only a test that uses char with *2 characters only*. You can make the size of the string dynamic by adding a `out int outValue` parameter to the C# function then adding `int* outValue` parameter to the C function. You can then write to this parameter on the C side the size of the character is and access that size from the C# side.

This size can then be passed to the last argument of the `Marshal.Copy` function and remove the current hard-coded *2* value limit. I will leave this for you to do but if confused, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424465/3785314) post for example of that.

---

The better solution is to pass `StringBuilder` to the native side then write to it. The bad side is that you have to declare the size of the `StringBuilder` on time.

**C++**:

```
void __cdecl  _GetLookupStatus (char* data, size_t size) 
{ 
    strcpy_s(data, size, "Test"); 
}
```

**C#**:

```
[DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int _GetLookupStatus(StringBuilder data, int size);

//Test
void Start() 
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(500);
    _GetLookupStatus (buffer, buffer.Capacity);
    string result = buffer.ToString();
}
```

---

If you are looking for the fastest way then you should use char array on the C# side, pin it on C# side then send it to C as `IntPtr`. On the C side, you can use  `strcpy_s` to modify the char array. That way, no memory is allocated on the C side. You are just re-using the memory of the char array from C#. You can see the `float[]` example at the end of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424465/3785314).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed clarification! I've added MakeStringCopy() to the code snippet.

Comment: One more question about not returning variables that are passed on the stack: Does it also apply to primitive data types? I did some tests and strings instantly fail, but int seems to work.

Comment: if it is int,float, bool, that's fine. If you are returning a reference of it with `&` or a pointer of it with `*` then its not fine. If it is an array such as `int []` or `int *` then it's not fine too since you are returning a memory address of it. It is fine if it is a variable that created with `malloc` in C or `new` keyword in C++ because they will be there even when you are outside the function. I think you should learn about returning references or pointers in a function. You will fully understand these.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks again to the clarification. C# marshaling is a complex beast if you just started with it. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Actually the answer on the 1st question is YES, it is a valid way to return a string from native function. According to Unity's doc: "String values returned from a native method should be UTF–8 encoded and allocated on the heap. Mono marshalling calls free for strings like this."