# Getting wrong byte values from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll

I'm building a plugin for Unity and looked at this answer for a method for reading byte data from C++ to C#:
[Passing byte array from C++ unmanaged dll to C# unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630063/passing-byte-array-from-c-unmanaged-dll-to-c-sharp-unity)

C++ code:

```
char DAQ_API* Read()
    {
         char Buffer[30];
         PopulateArray(Buffer);
         return Buffer;
    }
int DAQ_API FreeMemory(char* arrayPtr) 
    {
        if (arrayPtr != nullptr) {
            delete[] arrayPtr;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("DAQ")]
private static extern IntPtr Read();
[DllImport("DAQ")]
public static extern int FreeMemory(IntPtr ptr);
```

In the update loop:

```
IntPtr ptr = Read();
byte[] packet = new byte[30];
Marshal.Copy(ptr, packet, 0, 30);
FreeMemory(ptr);
```

The size of the byte array is 30, and the **first 8 bytes are correct**, and the rest looks like junk data:

```
0 240 0 89 86 23 7 9 240 67 189 31 0 0 0 0 96 211 95 0 0 0 0 0 224 210 95 0 0 0
```

What's happening that's causing the bad data for the rest of the array?

Comment: Where is the `new []`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/11683

Comment: `char DAQ_API* Read()` -- Undefined behavior since you're returning a pointer to a local variable.  When `Read` returns, that local array you declared becomes mush.

Comment: `if (arrayPtr != nullptr)` -- This check is not necessary.  It is perfectly ok to delete a nullptr.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.