# How to convert PInvoke `<[In](),Out()> ByRef` to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke, vb.net-to-c#

I have a function from this VB.net that needs to be imported to C#.
I have tried various VB.NET to C# converters but it does not work correctly with the imported dll associated with this function.
Anyone knows how to convert correctly for the following VB function to C#:

```
  <DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")> _
  Public Function E5K_ReadDIStatus(ByVal id As Short,<[In](),Out()> ByRef chnval As Integer) As Short
  End Function
```

Using an online converter, it gives the following:
Convert c# which has error

```
[DllImport("E5KDAQ.dll")]
public static extern short E5K_ReadDIStatus(short id, [In()] out int chnval);
```

[image]

Comment: Try `public static extern short E5K_ReadDIStatus(short id, [In(), Out()] ref int chnval);`.

Comment: `has error` Please put the error in **text** not an image.

Comment: In C#, `out` is used for parameters that are used for output only while `ref` is used for parameters that are used to provide input and output.  In VB, `ByRef` is used for both.  That's why attributes are used to qualify the `ByRef` keyword.  Those attributes clearly indicate that the `chnval` parameter is to be used for both input and output so that means that `ref` must be used in C#.  Because `ref` is unambiguous, you probably don't even need the attributes but, if you do include them, you obviously need both.

Comment: Thanks  Ahmed Abdelhameed,your solution works

Answer (score 2):

From official documentation here: http://www.acceed.de/manuals/inlog/EDAM5000_Manual.pdf there is a C++ definition, plus a bit of documentation on what the second parameter is, which is really what you want to look at:

> VC++: (see E5KDAQ.h)
>
> ```
> unsigned short E5K_ReadDIStatus (int id, unsigned long *Didata);
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> > id: module ID address
> >
> > Didata: points to a 32-bit buffer to store DI status

So the C# definition should simply be (`long` and `int` in C++ are 32-bit)

```
[DllImport("E5KDAQ")]
static extern ushort E5K_ReadDIStatus(int id, ref uint Didata)
```

Comment: Is there a reason the first parameter is not `int16`/`short`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - it's declared as `int` in C++

Comment: Oh, my bad. I don't really know C++ and for some reason, I had read what typed as _"long in C++ is 32-bit"_  (without _"and `int`"_ :D) so I assumed `int` would be 16-bit (like VB6, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
public static extern short E5K_ReadDIStatus(short id, ref int[] chnval)
```

Reference: [Are P/Invoke [In, Out] attributes optional for marshaling arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366066/are-p-invoke-in-out-attributes-optional-for-marshaling-arrays)